# Github login - is it possible restrict to a specific organization?

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, keycloak

If I enable Github as an Identity Provider in Keycloak does this mean that any user with a Github account can login successfully? What I am looking for is to limit logins to users that belong to my Github organization. I tried adding the OAuth application for my organization but I had some friends test and they were still able to login even though they do not belong to that organization.

Is it possible to use Github login but limit who can successfully login to those who belong to a specific Github organization?

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I ended up using SAML with our Azure Active Directory as the source.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best (and free) solution for you would be to install your own version of Gitlab on a local server of your organization, this way you can  make it only accessible to the members of the organization.

I know you were talking about Github and not Gitlab but I believe Github's entreprise version is not free. I don't know much about this subject however.

Comment: Thanks but I have other options I will consider before this. We have a private Github organization, just seeing if I can leverage that with an app where I am using Keycloak. I can also use SAML 2.0 as provider and tie into our corporate idenity but if I can use Github it would be easier for my needs.